# Conditionally compile if boost is present

Tags: c++, macos, boost, conditional-compilation

I want to conditionally compile some c++ code that uses boost, and make it so it doesn't try to compile the boost dependent code if boost is not present.

Does boost have any global macro that will be defined, like `__BOOST__`, that I can check for?

**EDIT:** It's clear to me now that I have to achieve this on the makefile level. I am working on OSX lion. Using gnu make

Comment: For such a macro to be defined, you'd first have to include a boost header... which will prove difficult if it isn't installed! My best bet would be to detect that at the makefile level. Answers will thus be dependent on your build system.

Comment: @syam good point, I wasn't thinking of that, but I still would like the conditional compilation to be done

Comment: Typically, you'd detect boost using your build facilities, and set a macro conditionally -- which you can then use for the conditional compilation. The latter part is easy, but we can't answer the first part without you telling us which build system / compiler / environment you're working with (eg. CMake, autotools, ...).

Comment: @aaronman Make your life easier by looking at something like CMake, Ant, Maven, Ninja, automake, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TYPICAL way that this is done is to use a "configuration script" or similar, that detects if the required/optional component(s) is/are present, and then selectively sets some -D options to the build system.

Obviously, if it's just your own project or a small distribution, you could do the same thing manually.

You probably also need a couple of `ifdef` type of choices in the Makefile if there are library files that you need.

One of the easier ways to determine if a part of boost that you need is installed is to try to compile it. If there are errors, the likely cause is that that part of boost isn't present (this obviously doesn't work if there are more important parts missing - for example, not having a compiler or standard library installed will ALSO cause a compile to fail. This is why nearly all configure type tools "start with the most basic features, and work their way up the tree of dependencies").

Comment: Not really helpful if you don't say how I can recognize if boost is installed or not, that's the only part I need to know the script I can write myself

Comment: @aaronman the thing is, `boost` is not a monolith, so it isn't clear how to define what "boost is installed" means.

Comment: @juanchopanza well if there is no way then I guess that is the answer

Comment: @aaronman: typically, the check consists in trying to build a minimal program that includes/links against all the boost components you need; if the compilation succeeds, you know you have the needed boost parts.

Comment: @MatteoItalia yeah I was just thinking of doing that

Comment: @aaronman: I actually thought this was so obvious I didn't have to write it, but I have now added "how you check if some part(s) of boost is installed". (This is just one of those things, what I think is "obvious" isn't necessarily obvious to someone else!)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I guess I was just hoping for some modification that BOOST made to the system you could check for